# SQL Database Ride Sharing

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I am designing a database for a ride sharing company(like Uber), it is from my home work actually. I have three tables - Driver,Customer and Ride, the customer and the driver have location attribute(latitude and longitude) which I represend them using double type. So my question is, can I make in SQL some arithmethic equation in order to the customer will get the closest car (using the location attributes) and in which table will be suit best the closest driver attribute in Customer or Ride?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the location of the cars and as well to the customers, check in google how you can keep track of a location, which geographical attributes you need.

Answer (score 0):

- For the first question, I'm not sure but here are some informations.

  - http://fr.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL
  - http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/
- And for the second, I think you don't have to store the closest driver attribute.